# Mathematica 12.1 a lot of text shown as "$Failed" on manjaro Linux.How could I solve it?

Tags: installation

[image]
After installing the mathematica with the official installer on manjaro , when I opened it , lots of UI texts were shown as "$Failed". However all functions works well in mathematica.

What's the cause behind this?

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: You should contact Wolfram technical support about this issue if you haven't already.

Comment: A good start might be deleting the directories mentioned in this article: support.wolfram.com/kb/12464, I can't say for sure if it will work or not though.

Comment: @ktm,that didn't solve the problem . I think I should consult the mathematica support.

Comment: @rsworktech, were you ever able to resolve the problem?

Comment: @AlectoIrenePerez Some one asked this question on Stack Overflow and got an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65689975/failed-in-the-mathematica-interface)

Comment: Hey, I found an answer that fixes everything without needing to enable ScreenResolutionCompatibilityMode https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/267261/44266